# Filtering table column using multiple wildcards

Tags: java, regex, filter, wildcard, talend

This question relates to Talend Open Studio but really lies within the Regex Java code realm.

I need to filter a MySQL table to

1. exclude a field name in one column and
2. pass  rows that contain permutations of keywords that occur within a string in multiple other columns.

Using tMySQLInput --> tMap --> tMySQLInput with !row1.CAT1.equals("IT") as an input expression I have succeeded with goal 1.

I have not been able to find out how to pass a list of wildcards using tFilterRow or any other component. The key words are %temp%, %recruit%, and %sourc%. (I use % because it is familiar to my MySQL queries.)

What I am hoping to find is something like: row1.ColumnName.contains(%temp%|%recruit%|%source%) that I can put in a variable regex expression filter in tMap or an advanced expression in tFilterRow.

I am new to Java coding so any best practices/advice/code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for the help, I have learned a lot from this community.

Comment: Can't you do the filtering in MySQL? The less data you pull out the faster your job will be.

Comment: I have considered that and have done it as a hold over for now but I'm looking for the "repeatable and automated" options that talend provides.

Comment: by pushing the filters to the database you save a lot of time and if you work with terabytes of data it will pay off

Comment: Thank you, I believe I will go that route. Would it be possible to pass the sql code to the database from a talend component and still have the power of the database engine do the work?

Comment: can you validate answer if its correct?

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
row3.Var1.contains("temp") || row3.Var1.contains("recruit") || row3.Var1.contains("source") ? row3.Var1 : ""
```

But is this what your asking for?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That gets me close but get this...when I put the ! statement of this... row1.Voucher_Header_Notes.contains("TEMP")||row1.Voucher_Header_Notes.contains("VIA")&&!row1.CAT1.equals("IT") ... at the beginning I get a different dataset. Does the expression put more weight on the parts in the beginning?

Comment: does your use of row3 instead of row1 imply that the expression should be entered in a certain location in tmap?

Comment: I cant get the include||exclude to work properly. I have tried row1.column.contains("X")||!(row1.column.contains("Y")), row1.column.contains("X")||!row1.column.contains("Y"), row1.column.contains("X")&&!(row1.column.contains("Y") to no avail. Should I look to use the exclude expression in a different component or different location in tmap? Should and Can I chain together a tfilter and a tmap?

Comment: No, you remplace row3 by the name of your input link in the tmap. For the !row1.CAT1.eq‌​uals("IT") you can use Relational.NOT("IT".equals(row1.Voucher_Hea‌​der_Notes)) (prefer "string".equals(Variable) instead of Variable.equals("string") in order to avoid null pointer error). Moreover you need parenthesis : 
(row1.Voucher_Header_Notes.contains("TEMP")||row1.Voucher_Hea‌​der_Notes.contains("‌​VIA")) && Relational.NOT("IT".equals(row1.Voucher_Hea‌​der_Notes))